# Reference Original Post Data in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out how to post the original field data along with its result to my results page.  I have an app written in Django that has two html pages. An input page and a results page.  The input page has a form. The result page has the output.  Here is the code I have in place:

models.py

```
class IssuingCA (models.Model):
    ICA_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    filepath = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.ICA_name
```

views.py (simplified version)

```
def index(request):
    issuers = IssuingCA.objects.order_by('ICA_name')
    issuerOptions = {'issuers': issuers}
    return render(request, 'index.html', issuerOptions)

def results(request):
    issuer = request.POST['selectedIssuer']
    issuername = 'Where I want the ICA_name value "icas" displayed'
    info = {'issuer': issuer, 'issuername': issuername}
    return render(request, 'results.html', info)
```

index.html

```
--snip--
<label for="selectedIssuers">Issuing CA</label>
    <select id="selectedIssuers" name="selectedIssuers">
    {% for icas in issuers %}
    <option value="{{ icas.filepath }}">{{ icas }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
--snip--
```

results.html

```
--snip--
<div>{{ issuer }}</div>
<div>{{ issuername }}</div>
--snip--
```

Let's set up a some sample data for the DB:
ICA_Name = "**squirrels**"; filepath = "**in/some/forest**"

The way the application works is that it presents a drop down in the index.html page that displays the `ICA_name` of all the values.  When you select the `ICA_name`, in this case, 'squirrels' and submit, it passes on the value of the option as the `filepath` for squirrels - "in/some/forest" which I request via POST and it displays on the results page.  What I want is a way to also show the original value of squirrels on the results page, such that for `issuer`, the text in the `<div>` shows **squirrels** (this currently works) and for `IssuerName`, the text in the `<div>` shows **in/some/forest**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must do it manually, put the primary key of the `IssuingCA` instance in the `value=` attribute of the `<option>`,

```
<option value="{{ icas.pk }}">{{ icas }}</option>
```

and then get the instance back in the results:

```
issuing_ca = IssuingCA.objects.get(pk=request.POST['selectedIssuers'])
info = {'issuer': issuing_ca.filepath, 'issuername': issuing_ca.ICA_name}
```

But if you're using Django, you will *definitely* want to use its forms.

Here is a tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial04/

and here is the complete documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/

Django provides better ways to manage input data that will protect you against all sorts of pitfalls. The

Comment: Hmm.. I never thought about using the pk value and referencing the fields off of that. I also did not know you could write {'issuer': issuing_ca.filepath}. You've taught me something new! I just tested this and it works! Thank you!  I have looked into forms previously and I intend to update my application to use them in a future version.

Comment: do it ASAP, don't wait. Even if not for the security features, it saves a lot of time, especially when maintaining/extending the already written code (which is always the main time sink).